# Calling .NET function from AutoCad

Tags: .net, autocad, autocad-plugin, dwg

Is it possible to call a .net Function from Autocad?

I want to know if I can call a .net function From AutoCad and run some calculations and update SQL Server with the output of that calculations.

Please refer some documentation if you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. It is a very popular way to automate AutoCAD.

I recently gave a couple answers on this topic.

First, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47723870/7159784) for a breakdown of some of the most common APIs. Follow the links in that post to find all the latest tutorials.

Second, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46897472/7159784) for information how to set yourself up in Visual studio and get developing.

Both posts have a number links to excellent developer resources.

Answer (score 3):

Calling commands from AutoCAD events using .NET is possible by using the [new API capabilities in AutoCAD 2016.](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2015/03/autocad-2016-for-developers.html)

[sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FExB1.gif)

**HERE :** [Some sort of opel source samples of new API](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2015/03/autocad-2016-calling-commands-from-autocad-events-using-net.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should start from [this page](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-C3F3C736-40CF-44A0-9210-55F6A939B6F2) specially [this exercice](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-BA686431-C8BF-49F2-946E-9CEB2F7AE4FA).